# Create a new OneToOne relation on the registration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-forms

I am new with Symfony and FOSUserBundle, I have a relation One To One between User and Stream, when a user want to register he check if he is a streamer or not. If he is a streamer I want to create a new stream in relation with the user so here is the registerAction from FOSUserBundle that I'm overriding :

```
$form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');
        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            /*This is what I added*/
            if($user->getIsStreamer()){
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $stream = new Stream();
                $stream->setUser($user);
                $em->persist($stream);
                $em->flush();
            }
            /********/
            $authUser = false;
            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $authUser = true;
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            if ($authUser) {
                $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
            }

            return $response;
        }
```

But nothing happened, what did I missed ?

Comment: A glimpse at your class properties involved in that relation might help.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the part that add the Stream to the user (and not only set the user of the stream).

First, be sure your association contains `cascade={"persist"}` to avoid need of manually persist the Stream :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Stream", cascade={"persist"},
 */
protected $stream;
```

Then, change your `setStream` to make it calling `$stream->setUser` automatically :

```
public function setStream(Stream $stream = null)
{
    $this->stream = $stream;
    $stream->setUser($this); // Setter calling

    return $this;
}
```

Now you can replace the logic of your condition like this :

```
if($user->getIsStreamer()){
    $stream = new Stream();
    $user->setStream($stream);
}
```

The association should be correctly stored when calling `$em->flush` at the end of your method.

In the case of FOSUB registration it should be :
`$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);`.
It's done in the `confirmAction` where your user is redirected in success.